# I need to duplicate a URL parameter and use a different parameter name in the URL

Tags: javascript, php, url

I need a simple way (PHP or Javascript) that can take the following URL and duplicate the email parameter with a new parameter name, append the new parameter to the URL before passing the URL to the webpage

**Start with this URL**

```
www.mydomain.com/page2/?contactId=123456&inf_contact_key=123456789&inf_field_FirstName=Jeff&inf_field_Email=jdg123%2540gmail.com
```

**Append it to include this:**

```
www.mydomain.com/page2/?contactId=123456&inf_contact_key=123456789&inf_field_FirstName=Jeff&inf_field_Email=jdg123%2540gmail.com&**email=jdg123%2540gmail.com**
```

I'm hoping a simple PHP script on an intermediary webpage can do the trick if there isn't a faster way.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems you have run into?

Comment: http://php.net/parse_str and http://php.net/http_build_query

Comment: Why do you need to duplicate it? Why are you not just using the data twice?

Comment: the webapge www.mydomain.com/page2/ is looking for the parameter [email] in the URL, otherwise the survey on that webpage will ask for the contacts email again at the end of the survey. I was hoping there was an easy way to create a PHP page before they land on the survey page using $_GET function to parse out the URL and then duplicate the inf_field_Email as another parameter email and then do some type of PHP redirect to the page

Comment: FYI… I found a javascript solution to my problem:

<script>
   function gup( name ) {
      var url = location.href
      name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
      var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
      var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
      var results = regex.exec( url );
      return results == null ? null : results[1];
   }
   if(gup('inf_field_FirstName') && gup('inf_field_Email') && !gup('email')){
      window.location=window.location = window.location.href+'&email='+gup('inf_field_Email')
   }
</script>

Comment: Code and input output should be in code blocks. Don't forget to add as many applicable tags, the URL tag really was a given. Those tags are likely followed by persons that perform these kind of transformations. If you find an answer, please post it as one. Nobody can easily read code in comments.